# Safety of Interpreting Integer as a Byte Array

Tags: c++, ios, endianness

I'm using a binary safe serialization method to transfer data between a client and server. And both are guaranteed to be little endian.

Rather than converting an `int64_t` value into a character string, is it safe to reinterpret it as a binary string for transport... then back into an `int64_t` upon arrival?

on client..

```
int64_t timeValue = 1554532128;
std::basic_string<char> timeString((const char *)timeValue, sizeof(int64_t));
```

and then on server..

```
std::basic_string<char> timeString;
int64_t timeValue = (int64_t)(*timeString.data());
```

Comment: Instead of `std::basic_string<char>` I'd prefer using `std::vector<uint8_t>` or `std::array<uint8_t,8>`, but with the same endianess it should be safe to use for transport.

Comment: Whether it is safe or not depends on how you are sending the string and constructing the string from the received data.

Comment: This is wrong I think `int64_t timeValue = (int64_t)(*timeString.data());`, better is `int64_t timeValue = *(int64_t*)(timeString.data());`

Comment: I'm using grpc to communicate two processes, and sometimes, when I have to send a struct and I don't want to define it on the proto (or it could be one of several possible structs that are well defined as POD), I use this method. I just set a string parameter, and construct it just this way. Care should be taken to construct the strings with **data and size** and not just pass the `char*`. However, I also make sure to check that `sizeof(expected_struct) == str.size()` on the receiving end (you should do `sizeof(int64_t) == timeString.size()` to know you're ok).

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use a `char*` pointer to access the raw bytes of a variable, the C++ standard has provisions for that use. But, you are not converting your values correctly, on either side. The code needs to look more like this instead:

```
int64_t timeValue = ...;
std::string timeString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&timeValue), sizeof(int64_t));
```

```
std::string timeString = ...;
//assert(timeString.size() == sizeof(int64_t));
int64_t timeValue = *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(timeString.data());
```